# Kubernetes job restarts even with restartPolicy: "Never"

Tags: kubernetes

I have a job with `restartPolicy: "Never"` which ends with "Error"

With `Status : Error` this job should not restart.

However, a new pod is created again and again each time the previous job fails :

```
$ kubectl get pods
kafka-pvbqk          0/1     Error              0          2m19s
kafka-ttt95          0/1     Error              0          109s
kafka-7fqgl          0/1     Error              0          69s
kafka-rrmlk          0/1     PodInitializing    0          2s
```

I know first thing should be to fix the error but I also want to understand why the pod restarts and how to avoid that ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the pod is never started properly so the notion of restart is not an issue here

Comment: For some time before the ' Error', I have `1/1 Running`, so I think the pod starts properly. The error comes from the return code in the job. But I still need to understand why the pod is recreated again and again

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is correct behavior and not a bug. The restart policy you're pointing to is about Pod, not a job itself.

To fail a Job after some amount of retries set `.spec.backoffLimit` to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed.

The back-off limit is set by default to 6. Failed Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s ...) capped at six minutes. The back-off count is reset when a Job's Pod is deleted or successful without any other Pods for the Job failing around that time.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know, thank you for the information. I can manually delete the job then, because I know the job was done correctly, it's just that the return code is not 0.